# How does "Proper MIME type for all files" page loading times or user experience in the browser

Tags: performance, .htaccess, mime-types, pageload

I see it in performance optimizations plugins for wordpress and even Paul Irish's HTML5 boilerplate in the .htaccess file.

I don't get how mine type affects performance. Don't browsers already know how to interpret these files? Why tell them how to do it a second time?

More importantly, how does this improve page loading times?

**Example**

```
# audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg

# video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4
AddType video/webm                     webm

# Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz 
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# webfonts                             
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType font/truetype                  ttf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular boilerplate, but I can see two reasons to do this:

- to make sure all file extensions are tied to the correct MIME type, so caching settings elsewhere in the configuration (which use the MIME type) are guaranteed to work
- to make sure the correct MIME type gets served along with each file, which is not relevant for performance but important nevertheless - HTTP doesn't know the concept of file extensions; the MIME type is the authoritative type identifier, and you can't rely on browsers knowing every file extension.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't improve loading times, but it does let these files work. IE doesn't let you use eot files unless they have the right MIME type, and some browsers are very fussy about audio and video types.